# How to properly create a startup script for tracd on Synology DS209+II?

Tags: trac, init.d, synology

I'm running [tracd](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone) on a Synology DS209+II NAS. For that purpose, I have created a script in `/opt/etc/init.d` called `S81trac`:

```
myserver> ls -l /opt/etc/init.d
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          127 May 19 09:56 S80apache
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          122 Jun 10 10:17 S81trac
```

This file has following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh    
# run tracd
/opt/bin/tracd -p 8888 -auth=*,/volume1/svn/svn-auth-file,mydomain -e /volume1/trac-env
```

And this actually works, except, the NAS never really finishes booting: The blue light keeps flashing. Also, `reboot` doesn't work anymore (it hangs) and I have to use `killall init` to reboot the machine.

I have tried running `tracd` in the background, by appending `&` to the last line of `S81trac`. After rebooting, the blue light stops flashing. But `ps | grep tracd` is empty and I can't connect to the trac instance from my PC.

I guess I'm doing something wrong here, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `&` to background it, use `--daemonize` (or the shorter form `-d`).  I think that should address your problem.  (You may want to consider using `--pidfile=...` as well.  `tracd --help` would also be worth perusing.)

<sub>Disclosure: I am one of the Trac Devs.</sub>